# How to fetch data from multiple multiselect dropdowns?

Tags: php, multi-select

```
<form action="a.php" method="post">

<select id="sel_1" name="sel[]" multiple>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<select id="sel_2" name="sel[]" multiple>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<input type="submit"/>

</form>
```

Now when i am trying to fecth the data like this

```
$offer = $_POST['sel'];
print_r($offer);
```

its displaying data like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1          // 1, 2 selected for sel_1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 2          // 2, 3 selected for sel_2
    [3] => 3
)
```

Shouldn't it come like this?

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array(
                   [0] => 1
                   [2] => 2
                 )
    [1] => Array(
                   [0] => 2
                   [2] => 3
                 )
)
```

I want to create string data like this(in the nxt a.php file):

```
for sel_1 data is created like "1, 2";
for sel_2 data is created like "2, 3";
```

How can i fetch the data in the above format.

I am trying this

```
for($i = 0; $i<count($offer) ; $i++)
{
   for($j = 0; $j<count($offer[$i]); $j++)
   {
       $string = $tring. $offer[$i][$j];
   }
}
```

Comment: did you find a solution to your question ?

Answer (score 1):

Set the names `sel1[]` and `sel2[]` (different). In PHP you can use `array_merge`  to obtain another array with the values from the first and from the second array:

```
$offer = array_merge($_POST['sel1'], $_POST['sel2']);

$string = '';
for($i = 0; $i < count($offer); $i++)
{
    $string .= $offer[$i];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this,it's working as per your requirement:

Instead of this

```
$offer = $_POST['sel'];
```

Put like this

```
 $offer[] = $_POST['sel'];
```

**Code:-**

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <select id="sel_1" name="sel1[]" multiple>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>

    <select id="sel_2" name="sel2[]" multiple>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit"/>

    </form>
<?php
error_reporting(0);
    $offer=array();
    $offer[] = $_POST['sel1'];
    $offer[]= $_POST['sel2'];
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($offer);
    echo "</pre>";
    ?>
```

For output click here: [Output](http://codepad.viper-7.com/Hi1y3t)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<form action="a.php" method="post">

<select id="sel_1" name="sel[1][]" multiple>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<select id="sel_2" name="sel[2][]" multiple>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<input type="submit"/>

</form>
```

Worked for me